# How can I use a @Html.DropDownList with multiple values

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a table `Medicine` with column `ID`,`MedicineName` and `price`

Now I have this `@Html.DropDownList` populated by the table medicine. I want to include the value `ID`,`MedicineName` and `price` the call or use it in jquery.

currently I can only get the `MedicineName`

My controller:

```
 public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.ClientID = new SelectList(db.Clients, "ClientID", "Surname");
        ViewBag.MedicineID = new SelectList(db.Medicines, "MedicineID", "MedicineName");
        return View();
    }
```

My view:

```
 @Html.DropDownList("MedicineID", ViewBag.MedicineID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Script:

```
 $("#btnAdd").click(function () {

        var medname = $("#MedicineID option:selected").text()
        var qty = $("#myID").val()

        $("#tblList").append('<tr> <td>' +medname+ '</td>  <td>'+qty+'</td>  <td>   </td>  <td><a class="remove" href="#">del</a></td></tr>')

    })
```

Comment: What you can do is make ID the value and have MedicineName-Price as text in the dropdown. But this will mean the user will get to see both Medicine Name and Price in his selection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to send formatted data inside your dropdown from controller action method.You can use something like this:

```
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
            ViewBag.ClientID = new SelectList(db.Clients, "ClientID", "Surname");

           //modified code
            var medlist = db.Medicines.AsEnumrable().Select(x => new {Id = x.MedicineID, MedName = (x.Id + " "+ x.MedicineName +" "+ x.Price).ToString()});
            ViewBag.MedicineID = new SelectList(medlist, "ID", "MedName");
            return View();
        }
```

Now you are able to see id,name and price for your medicine inside dropdown. You can format dropdown as per your need. 
And you can extract your data in script by placing appropriate string functions.

Answer (score 0):

You cant store 3 values in each row of select list. It has only Id and Text.

What you can do is to onchange call a webapi and ask for additional data using id you get from select list.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `@Html.DropDownList`, it only allows 2 data values: id and text.

Instead you can use `@Html.NameFor` and `@Html.IdFor` to build your own drop down:

```
<select name="@Html.NameFor(Function(model) model.CityId)"
        id="@Html.IdFor(Function(model) model.CityId)">
    @For Each medicine In Model.Medicines
        @<option value="@medicine.MedicineId"
                 data-price="@medicine.price">
            @medicine.MedicineName
        </option>
    Next
</select>
```